# How to truncate authors' given names using BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am working on a research paper and I have a question regarding the formatting of references.

Presently my references are typeset in this format:

```
GivenName(s) LastName ...
```

However, I would like to typeset the references in the following format:

```
First letter(s) of GivenName(s). LastName, ...
```

My question is: What do I need to do to tell BibTeX to implement my desired format for given names?

Note that I am using the following citation management package and bibliography style:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify whether it's ok or not to sort the entries alphabetically by authors' surnames.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're otherwise fine with the `unsrtnat` bibliography style, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `unsrtnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `unsrtnat-trunc.bst`. (Don't edit an original file from any TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `unsrtnat-trunc.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex file(s) will do fine.
- In the file, search for the following line (it's line 222 in my copy of `unsrtnat.bst`):

  ```
      { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Change this line to

  ```
      { s nameptr "{f.}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```
- Save the file `unsrtnat-trunc.bst` either in the folder that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. If you have no idea what the preceding sentence means, I suggest you select the former option.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-trunc}` and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

% create a sample bib file "on the file"
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{ab:3001,
  author = "Anna Adele Andersen and Brenda Bettina Branson",
  title  = "Structured Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
@misc{yz:3002,
  author = "Yves Ysidro Yakovlev and Zeno Zebulon Zhang",
  title  = "Random Thoughts",
  year   = 3002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-trunc}

\begin{document}
\cite{yz:3002,ab:3001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. I am using overleaf and so I am not finding "unsrtnat.bst". Could u pls suggest any other way

Comment: @Heretolearn - You're welcome. If you can't find the file on Overleaf itseld, I suggest your Google it as follows: `ctan unsrtnat.bst`. Click on a suitable choice and save the file that you open under the name `unsrtnat-trunc.bst` in your main work folder in Overleaf.